# XmlDocument vs. Custom Classes

Tags: xml, vb.net, performance, xml-parsing

I'm currently developing an application that audits a filesystem based on an XML file. I've done extensive work in trying to reduce memory consumption and CPU time and it seems that functions regarding `XmlDocument.SelectNodes` and `XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode` are among the remaining "bottlenecks". I'm curious if

- I'm chasing rainbows at this point
- If it's worth creating a class structure to define the dynamic settings that are stored in the XmlDocument.

My reason for reducing the load is because a single audit, currently, takes about 25 minutes to compare files/folders against this settings document while generating an HTML report of its findings in a filesystem with about 120,000 files/folders.